# How to re-evaluate promhttp.Handler on database change?

Tags: go, microservices, prometheus

I'm perhaps abusing `promhttp.Handler()` to realise the use case for my microservice to tell me the:

- version
- if it has database connectivity

If there is a better way to monitor my microservices, do let me know!

I'm not sure how to structure the handle in such a way that when /metrics are called, the [db.Ping()](https://godoc.org/database/sql#DB.Ping) is re-evaluated.

https://s.natalian.org/2019-06-02/msping.mp4

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "os"

    _ "github.com/go-sql-driver/mysql"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus"
    "github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus/promhttp"
)

const version = "0.0.1"

type App struct {
    Router *mux.Router
    DB     *sqlx.DB
}

func main() {
    a := App{}
    a.Initialize()

    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+os.Getenv("PORT"), a.Router))
}

func (a *App) Initialize() {
    connectionString := "root:secret@tcp(localhost:3306)/rest_api_example?multiStatements=true&sql_mode=TRADITIONAL&timeout=5s"
    var err error
    a.DB, err = sqlx.Open("mysql", connectionString)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    microservicecheck := prometheus.NewGaugeVec(
        prometheus.GaugeOpts{
            Name: "mscheck",
            Help: "Version with DB ping check",
        },
        []string{
            "commit",
        },
    )

    if a.DB.Ping() == nil {
        microservicecheck.WithLabelValues(version).Set(1)
    } else {
        microservicecheck.WithLabelValues(version).Set(0)
    }

    prometheus.MustRegister(microservicecheck)

    a.Router = mux.NewRouter()
    a.initializeRoutes()
}

func (a *App) initializeRoutes() {
    a.Router.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler()).Methods("GET")
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/9DdXnz77S55

Comment: Implement and register a [Collector](https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#Collector). It will be called for each /metric request. See the example in the docs to get started.

Comment: You are not abusing the use cases, this is quite common (See [robust perception article](https://www.robustperception.io/exposing-the-software-version-to-prometheus) about version. About ping, it is more common to make metrics request and set a down status when you couldn't join the service. An alternative is to return an error code since it may not make sense to expose metrics if the service is not joinable and it will be reported it in the target `up` metric.

Comment: Collector example seems a little complex! https://godoc.org/github.com/prometheus/client_golang/prometheus#Collector

Comment: @MichaelDoubez couldn't find a simple example of returning an error code when a ping fails https://github.com/search?l=Go&q=prometheus.NewProcessCollector+%22db.Ping%28%29%22+up&type=Code

Comment: This is where I'm at https://play.golang.org/p/NhlVgt2oOrJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also add a middleware hook that does a [preflight routine](https://medium.com/statuscode/how-i-write-go-http-services-after-seven-years-37c208122831) (i.e. your ping test) before calling `promhttp.Handler()`. However, at collection time, I think metrics should already have been tallied; and not generated at the instance of collection. So...

Try a separate go-routine that will poll the health of the DB connection at regular intervals. This avoids any messy hooks or custom collectors:

```
var pingPollingFreq = 5 * time.Second // this should probably match the Prometheus scrape interval

func (a *App) Initialize() {       
    // ...

    prometheus.MustRegister(microservicecheck)

    go func() {
        for {
            if a.DB.Ping() == nil {
                microservicecheck.WithLabelValues(version).Set(1)
            } else {
                microservicecheck.WithLabelValues(version).Set(0)
            }
            time.Sleep(pingPollingFreq)
        }
    }()

    // ...
}
```